# Parse pseudo XML tag to an array

Tags: php, parsing

I have following string:

```
$input = '[gallery ids="1151,1150,1149,1148,1147" name="ponny"]';
```

I need to parse it into an array, so desired output should looks like:

```
$output = array(
  'ids'  => '1151,1150,1149,1148,1147',
  'name' => 'ponny'
);
```

Pseudo tag name `gallery` will be ignored.

What is the most efficient way to do this in PHP ?

Comment: Maybe you could use [the BBCode parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php), but I don't know if this works with multiple arguments. (BBCode usually has one argument per tag, right after the tag name, e.g. [img=myimage.jpg])

Comment: I do not want to involve here any external PHP library.

Comment: Do you have a non-efficient way to do it you're not happy with?

Comment: This is a PECL extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how efficient it is, but you could just turn the input into XML:

```
$input = '[gallery ids="1151,1150,1149,1148,1147" name="ponny"]';

$xml = str_replace( array( '[', ']' ), array( '<', ' />' ), $input );

var_dump( new SimpleXMLElement( $xml ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

As simplest solution you can extract values between quotes

```
$input = '[gallery ids="1151,1150,1149,1148,1147" name="ponny"]';
preg_match_all('/\"([^\"]*?)\"/', $input, $matches);
$output = array(
    'ids'  => $matches[1][0],
    'name' => $matches[1][1]
);
```

The output of `var_dump($output)` is

```
array (size=2)
  'ids' => string '1151,1150,1149,1148,1147' (length=24)
  'name' => string 'ponny' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$idsStart=strpos('ids',$input);
$idsValueStart=strpos('"',$input,$idsStart);
$idsValueEnd=strpos('"',$input,$idsValueStart);
$ids=substr($input,$idsValueStart,$idsValueEnd-$idsValueStart);
$nameStart=strpos('name',$input);
$nameValueStart=strpos('"',$input,$nameStart);
$nameValueEnd=strpos('"',$input,$nameValueStart);
$name=substr($input,$nameValueStart,$nameValueEnd-$nameValueStart);
$output=array();
$output[]=$ids;
$output[]=$name;
```

not terribly efficient looking, but if the order of the variables in the gallery array changes it should still give you the right answer.